# Kotlin class type parameter: Mismatch undetected

Tags: java, kotlin

**Kotlin Code:**

```
class Inva<T>{
    fun <T> x(y:T) {}
}

fun main(args: Array<Integer>) {
    var inva = Inva<Int>()
    inva.x(“123”)
}
```

**Java Equivalent:**

```
public class Vab<T> {

    void x(T y) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Vab<Integer> vab = new Vab<Integer>();

       vab.x("123");

   }
}
```

Why does the Kotlin code allow the invariant, whereas the Java code is flagged correctly as invalid?

Comment: How are those programs equivalent? The first class is a generic class having a generic member, the second is just a generic class.

Comment: They both try to place an invariant property as an argument to a method. They may not be precisely the same but the kotlin code highlights placing a string into an invariant method. Java flags this as a compile type error (expecting int), Kotlin allows it to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These code snippets are *not equivalent*, since the Java snippet uses the type parameter of its class instead of declaring its own.

A comparable Java method declaration would be like this (note the additional `<T>` on the method itself):

```
<T> void x(T y) {}
```

And with this change, the Java class would compile just like the Kotlin variant.

Comment: Exactly. Shadowing is exactly the behavior one would expect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `main` signature is wrong, you should use `Array<String>` instead of `Array<Integer>`.

Your class has a type parameter `T`, which is completely unused. The embedded function `x` also has a type parameter `T`, which is independent of the class type parameter. You can change the function signature as follows:

```
class Inva<T>{
    fun x(y:T) {}
}
```

Now your call will fail as expected: *Type mismatch*.